# SQL: count of rows with lowest timestamp in Hive

Tags: sql, count, hive

In my Hive table, I have the following:

```
mydate,user_id,source,timestamp
20160901,10293,google,2016-09-01 00:21:06
20160901,34393,yelp,2016-09-01 05:23:00
20160901,38437,fb,2016-09-01 12:03:24
20160902,34393,google,2016-09-02 13:44:55
```

...

The source denotes the referral location of the user and can be from yelp, google, fb, bing and so on - this referral denotes what kind of account the user has.
The user_id is unique throughout the table and I'm trying to find the distribution of sources over the past year.

I could do something like

```
sum(IF(source = 'fb',1,0)) fb_count,
sum(IF(source = 'yelp',1,0)) yelp_count
... from my_table where mydate between blah and foo.
```

However, the complication here is that users can switch their account types. For instance, a user can switch their user type from (say) google to bing after their account is created. So to fix this, I need to select the source corresponding to the first timestamp in the table, which would correspond to the time the user account was created.

Essentially: find the count of each user type where the count is done for the lowest timestamp for that user_id.

The result would look like:

```
month,fb_count,google_count,yelp_count,bing_count
201601,1667,3403,304,4340
201602,367,343,34,434
```

...

I could use a self join but that would be pretty expensive. Is there a better way?

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: @vkp Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first registered time of a user using `row_number` window function and then use conditional aggregation.

```
select year(mydate),month(mydate), 
sum(IF(source = 'fb',1,0)) fb_count,
sum(IF(source = 'yelp',1,0)) yelp_count
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by user_id order by timestamp) rn
      from tablename t) x
where rn = 1 --add a date filter if necessary
group by year(mydate),month(mydate)
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks!